# FFMPEG h.264 stream to VLC from raw YUV444 produces black screen and audio noise

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, h.264

I am piping raw YUV444 640x480 frames to ffmpeg from inside a C++ program using stdout (Pipe format: pipe<-Y<-U<-V whole frames each). ffmpeg encodes them using h.264 and streams the video via UDP to an IP of my choice.

When I am not streaming and saving the video on the recording device as -mp4 file with ffmpeg, everything works - But when I stream over the network and try to receive in VLC, the stream is received and the playing timer under the video screen runs,**but the image is black, none of the video is displayed.** Also I have some crackling sounds on my audio output. The raw video does not have an audio track.

My ffmpeg settings are as follows:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -f rawvideo -r 25 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p -s 640x480 -i - -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -framerate 25 -f mpegts udp://192.168.150.1:20001
```

in VLC (GUI), I just use "open network stream" with udp://@:20001. The port is open, I tested it with a simple dummy sender/receiver. Almost the same cli arguments for the video recording lead to a perfectly playable video when writing to a file and downloading it:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -f rawvideo -r 25 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv444p -s 640x480 -i - -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -framerate 25 video.mp4
```

If I try to stream the same recorded video using

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://192.168.150:20001
```

I get a black screen again, like above.

The VLC log output identifies my stream as mp3, so maybe stream type recognition is to blame. But why?

Here are the [ffmpeg console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KYe4.png) and the [VLC log](https://pastebin.com/2agAg1Jf).

**What am I doing wrong?**

PS: Moved this question over here from Stack Overflow because it was not getting any answers, old unanswered duplicate is deleted.

Comment: Do other players receive it ok?

Comment: Wohoo! You were totally on the right track. I tried SMPlayer and PotPlayer (What a name) and PotPlayer could play it! The question remains: Why doesn't VLC?

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Update: I tried also with OpenCV(Python3)'s VideoCapture. This produces a highly corrupted image and a ton of "error while decoding". Could it be that VLC and OpenCV use the same decoder, which has problems with h.264?

Comment: Appears to be related to this: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/21024. Downgrade VLC or use another player.

Comment: Downgrading did the Trick, I am baffled that this is necessary, hopefully the issue gets fixed soon. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the underlying issue has not been resolved, @Gyans hints helped me to solve my problem. Using other players (PotPlayer) or an older version of VLC got the stream display to work, and that is all I needed.